# Auto complete filter function only works after type something

Tags: html, typescript, filter, angular6, mat-autocomplete

The drop down value should be appear when the user touches the input field, but my drop down only appears after I type something in the input.

This is my HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" style="width:100%">
    <input placeholder="Vacancy" formControlName="job" [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let job of filteredJobs | async" [value]="job">
        {{job?.refId}} - {{job?.title}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

And here are my type script functions:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getAllVacancyDetails();

    this.filteredJobs = this.vacancyForm.controls['job'].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((possition: string | null) => possition ? this._filterJobs(possition) : this.jobs)
    );
  }


public getAllVacancyDetails() {
    this.vacancyService.getAllvacancies().subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.jobs = res.body;
        }
      },
      err => {
        this.openSnackbar("An Error Occured while Loading Dropdown Data");
      }
    );
  }

     private _filterJobs(value: any): Job[] {
        let jobsList: Job[] = new Array();
        if (!(value instanceof Object)) {

          const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
          this.jobs.forEach(job => {
            if (job.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0) {
              jobsList.push(job);
            }
          });
          if(jobsList.length == 0){
            this.vacancyForm.controls['job'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
          }
        }


    return jobsList;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because  getAllVacancyDetails() is async and when you emit null with startWith(null) - **this.jobs** hasn't received job list from Backend yet. So you need to notify this.filteredJobs stream once jobs was loaded. You could fix it somehow like this:

1.In typescript file add a new property:

```
private _loadedJobs$ = new Subject()
```

2. In **getAllVacancyDetails()** method (just after `this.jobs = res.body;`) add a string `this._loadedJobs$.next('');`
3. Modify your **this.filteredJobs** stream like this:

   this.filteredJobs = merge(this.vacancyForm.controls['job'].valueChanges,
   this._loadedJobs$.next('')).pipe( ...same what do you have now )

I am quite sure that there are more elegant way to fix or rework it but I just wanted to give you some hint :) Hope it will help. Also there is example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-autocomplete-qrlhaf?file=src/app/app.component.ts